# Padding an image in Python

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing

I am trying to add columns and rows on all sides.

```
padded_array = np.zeros([img.shape[0] + (size//2) + (size//2), img.shape[1] + (size//2) + (size//2)])
padded_array[size//2 : padded_array.shape[0]-(size//2), size//2 : padded_array.shape[1]-(size//2)] = gray
```

Here, `img` is the original image and `gray` is the gray-scaled image and `shape` of both of them is `same`.
Now, I am trying to create a `padded_array` by adding `(size//2) rows` on top and below and
`(size//2) columns` left and right.

`size` is always `odd`.

When I try to pad, I don't understand why the gray image is not broadcasted into the padded array.
Instead, what it is doing is broadcasting value `255` on all pixels in that range of gray image and padded rows and columns are left blank.

I am adding the screenshots of both the images, please have a look.

1. Gray Scale Image is :

[image]

2. Padded Image after broadcasting gray is :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide `image width / image height` and multiply with a constant.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def pad(image, h=2):
    w = (image.shape[0]/image.shape[1]) * h
    plt.figure(figsize=(w, h))
    plt.imshow(im)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()


im = plt.imread('blur.png')
pad(im)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I want to do it without using OpenCV.

Comment: But you tag the question as `opencv`.

Comment: Please see my new answer.

Comment: Yeah, that's appreciated, but can u find and tell me where my code is going wrong?

Comment: I didn't understand your code. Therefore I propose mine.

Comment: If you tell me how you wanted to achieve the result, then I maybtry to explain

Comment: gray is my image
padded array is my image where I am trying to add rows and columns on all sides.
and in the centre of padded array I want the values of gray to be copied there.

Comment: Look at my code, it is exactly doing what you told me

Answer (score 0):

The mistake here was while defining the `padded_array` I didn't define the data type of array to be int, it was float by default and that was the reason for white image, as soon as I defined the data in padded_array are int, everything turned out fine.